# How can I find the user who performed a database transaction?

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL database. Suppose a database "X". It is used by multiple users. I want to find those users who performed any transaction of data into this database. Is it possible?

Can I find it from MySQL binary log? How?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can find what you are looking for in mysql log files.
[Binary Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/binary-log.html) keeps track of the transactions that describe database changes such as table creation operations or changes to table data.

[Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html) keeps track of all operations including Select and Show statements.

Both log files describe the action with the **user who performed** it.

This [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html) is a tutorial for how to read binary log file.